# Running app/VPN for a single user

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn

So I have done research in regards to installing an app for a single user, I have a VPN app which I can install on ubuntu desktop, but it installs system wide, on a second user account when I launch the app it remains in its same session that it was on the first users account.

Although if this is possible I don't know if it would work because I believe system wide the network is the same network and not separate for all users

What I would like to do:
Run a VPN on separate user accounts, user1 will use my VPN app Nord VPN on that session, and switch to user2 and launch Nord VPN and connect to another server.  User 1 will be connected to let's say US Server 1, and user2 will be connected to US Server 2

How does anyone think I can establish this?

If I can have separate sessions as both users I have no doubt that it would work, but unfortunately there's no way to separate both user1 and user2 sessions, and they work system wide as a whole, so applications like Nord VPN just launch as the same instance...